# Using client cert with supertest

Tags: supertest

I'm trying to test a REST API using supertest and the server requires a client cert.  Below is both my supertest test which isn't send the client cert as well as a test using Node's https library directly that does send the cert.  I'd like to port the Node-https-based test to supertest because of its fluid API, but I can't see where to set the client cert.

Supertest test - doesn't work because client cert isn't sent to server:

```
request('https://server.dev:443')
  .post('/stuff')
  .send(postData)
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .expect(200, done);
```

Existing Node https test that sends client cert (for reference):

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'server.dev',
  port: 443,
  path: '/stuff',
  method: 'POST',
  cert: cert,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
  }
};
options.agent = new https.Agent(options);

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log('no more data in response.')
    done();
  })
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  done(e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```